# Why have extra values been added to my database?

Tags: php, sql, database, sql-injection

I have a website which lists products available in my shop, which is populated from a products table from a SQL database.  I have written the site in PHP.

Overnight some extra values have been added to my products table.  20 extra rows have been added with the values "admin" and "adminu" over and over again.

I don't understand how this has happened but suspect it is something to do with SQL injection?

Comment: Yes, almost certainly SQL injection attempts.

Comment: Is that site need any authorized login?

Comment: It could be SQL injection attempts but not actual SQL injection holes. Instead, it's probably permission issues, where you're allowing a route to insert products without authorization.

Comment: Yes, it does need authorized login , which is a bit worrying